# Does anybody know how this type of hover animation effect is created?

Tags: jquery, animation, icons

Hi I've seen this type of animation used a lot lately. I've been trying to look into how this could be achieved and found plugins such as spritely, but just wondering if I'm missing something or if there is a better way of achieving such effects.

Here's an example of the kind of animation I'm talking about:

http://byassociationonly.com/about/

(the icon animations in the orange circles)

Any tips or advice would be great.

Comment: I would guess it is a css3 animation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: Those images are animated gif as you can see with the firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the source code of the website and how they do it is via CSS using ":hover". It is also possible to use javascript but I feel it would be much easy using CSS.

Example of CSS code:

```
#divName{
 background: url(linkToImage);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#divName:hover{
 background: url(linkToGIF);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks people! Thought there may have been more trickery than just using animated gifs.

Comment: I have seen some weird and very complicated ways of doing it. I must admit that I have done something a really complicated way when it could have been solved in one or two lines.

Answer (score 1):

They use css to change the background image. When you hover the div the background switches to an [animated gif](http://byassociationonly.com/wp-content/themes/ByAssociationOnly/img/about3.gif)